# VBA Insert page without headers

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to insert new pages at the end of an word document without headers and footers. After some research here, I have the following code. But the code does not remove headers.

```
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage

With Selection.PageSetup
 .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
 .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(0.2)
 .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(0)
End With


ActiveDocument.Sections(wdActiveEndSectionNumber).Headers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).LinkToPrevious = False
ActiveDocument.Sections(wdActiveEndSectionNumber).Headers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).Range.Delete
ActiveDocument.Sections(wdActiveEndSectionNumber).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).LinkToPrevious = False
ActiveDocument.Sections(wdActiveEndSectionNumber).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Delete
ActiveDocument.Sections(wdActiveEndSectionNumber).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
ActiveDocument.Sections(wdActiveEndSectionNumber).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Delete
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by not remove the headers? Does the header have any content?

Comment: yes, they have after running these lines furthermore content

Comment: What content? Shapes? pictures? lines? text?

Comment: theres one picture

Comment: BTW, the margins you have set are very likely to be outside the printable area, which is defined by the capabilities of the currently assigned printer.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have deleted the text you have not deleted any shapes that may be in the header. The following code will clear the headers of all text and any shapes.

```
  Dim numShapes As Long, index As Long
  With ActiveDocument.Sections.Last
    With .Headers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages)
      .LinkToPrevious = False
      .Range.Delete
      numShapes = .Shapes.Count
      If numShapes > 0 Then
        For index = numShapes To 1 Step -1
          .Shapes(index).Delete
        Next index
      End If
    End With
    With .Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
      .LinkToPrevious = False
      .Range.Delete
      numShapes = .Shapes.Count
      If numShapes > 0 Then
        For index = numShapes To 1 Step -1
          .Shapes(index).Delete
        Next index
      End If
    End With
    With .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
      .LinkToPrevious = False
      .Range.Delete
      numShapes = .Shapes.Count
      If numShapes > 0 Then
        For index = numShapes To 1 Step -1
          .Shapes(index).Delete
        Next index
      End If
    End With
  End With
```

On a technical level there is no such thing as a section without headers or footers. Even if they have no printable content they still exist and contain an end of paragraph character.